# How to write into an existing textfile in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, filestream, file-handling

If this is the code in opening a textfile "word.txt" in my solution explorer.

```
       Stream txtStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new   Uri("/sample;component/word.txt", UriKind.Relative)).Stream;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtStream))
        {
            string jon;
            while (!sr.EndOfStream) 
            {
              jon = sr.ReadLine();
              mylistbox.ItemSource = jon;
            }
        }
```

How do i write and append in the existing textfile?

Comment: [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx).

Comment: Create a StreamWriter, the docs will tell you how to set append mode.

Comment: The StreamWriter won't be enough, you can't write into the application resources. You'll have to copy the file to the isolated storage before modifying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example

```
    public static void WriteBackgroundSetting(string currentBackground)
    {
        const string fileName = "RecipeHub.txt";
        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if(myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
                myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);
            var stream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
            using (StreamWriter isoStream = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                isoStream.WriteLine(currentBackground);
            }
        }

    }
```