# Can't write to a text file in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Ok so I need to write to a text file on my home network in c#. The problem is that I cant use anything with `System.IO.File` because it is not supported on Windows Phone. I'm trying to use `System.IO.StreamWriter` but this is creating a problem.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter ow;
ow = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"\\RASPBERRYPI\pi\led.txt");
```

This is as far as I have got and it says:

> "Cannot convert from string to System.IO.Stream"

I have been searching for an answer for this but nobody seems to have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Windows Phone [does not support](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d2b4fd04-a7d5-41e6-9fa1-ae0943d2f84d/windows-phone-8-sdk-access-network-share?forum=wpdevelop) accessing SMB / network file shares.

Answer (score 1):

Read the `StreamWriter` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for Windows phone; it takes a `System.IO.Stream`, not a `string` and there is no such thing as `System.IO.string`.

If you can actually write to a path (and if you can't check out [isolated storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18945358/22437)) you can do this:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"\\RASPBERRYPI\pi\led.txt", FileMode.CreateNew)
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    writer.Write(textToAdd);
}
```

Comment: sorry the string thing was my mistake, it did say System.IO.Stream

Comment: It doesn't recognise FileStream or FileMode.

Comment: @JoeSpeers for that you need to add one `using statement` on top of the file. like this: `using System.IO.` You can also resolve this by right click on the word `FileStream` and select first option to add using statement.

Comment: What makes you think “It doesn't recognise FileStream”? Do you get an error message? Tell us the message. Did you add the System.IO and other DLLs to your project (from Project > Add Reference in Visual Studio)? Merely typing a class name from a DLL in your source file does not add the DLL to your project.

Comment: When I try to reference System.IO it says that it is already referenced. The errors are: `The type or namespace name 'FileStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` (line 56) and `The name 'FileMode' does not exist in the current context` (line 56)

Comment: Explain how you “try to reference System.IO”. What does “it says that it is already referenced” mean? You get an error message? Whenever you get an error message please [tell us the message](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabflavor/article/please_please_please/). Don't try to paraphrase it or guess what is wrong, just copy the error message and put it right into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a small example to illustrate writing (and reading). This is my xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <RichEditBox Name="inputTxtBx" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 AcceptsReturn="True"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="write" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Write"
            Click="write_Click"/>
    <TextBlock Name="outputTxtBlk" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
               Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Name="read" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Content="Read" Click="read_Click" Margin="5"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Name="delete" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Content="Delete" Click="delete_Click" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And this is the code behind illustrating reading and writing to a file on a windows phone:

```
private async void write_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await WriteToFile();
}

private StorageFile file;
private async Task WriteToFile()
{
    // Create a new file named "outputFile.txt"
    file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("outputFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    // Get the string in inputBx
    string toWrite;
    inputTxtBx.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.AdjustCrlf, out toWrite);

    // Write the data from the textbox
    using(var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        using(var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync(toWrite);
        }
    }

    inputTxtBx.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.ApplyRtfDocumentDefaults, "");
}

private async void read_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(file == null)
    {
        outputTxtBlk.Text = "You have to write first!";
    }
    else
    {
        // Read the data from disk
        using(var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                outputTxtBlk.Text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}

private async void delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(file == null)
    {
        outputTxtBlk.Text = "You have to write first!";
    }
    else
    {
        await file.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
        outputTxtBlk.Text = "File purged forever!";
        file = null;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: it dosent like storageFile, Task, ApplicationData, CreationCollisionOption, TextGetOptions, and a few more things?

Comment: @Joe Speers These were my include statements :
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Text;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

Note that you don't have to use a RichEditBox, a simpler TextBox would be fine and the logic would be easier.

Comment: Ok that fixed a lot just 2 errors now: `The Name 'TextGetOptions' does not exist in the current context` (line 44) and `The Name 'TextSetOptions' does not exist in the current context` (line 55).

Comment: Those enumerations are only available on windows phone 8.1. Which are you developing for? It might be easier to clean up all that mess and just use a TextBlock and obtain the contents by using the Text property.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.IO;
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Text.txt"))
{
    sw.WriteLine("bla");
}
```

Try this.

Comment: hmm it gives me lots of errors about brackets and semi colons

Comment: well it works perfectly for me... what is the exact error message?

Comment: `StreamWriter(string path)` is Win32, not Windows Phone.